# Method inside PowerShell class

Tags: powershell

I wanted to define class in PowerShell. Inside that class I wanted to use function defined elsewhere, so that when one asks for that value it is automatically run when needed. Following is an example of this.

```
class ActiveDirectoryUser {
    $DisplayName
    $LastName
    $FirstName
    $FirstNameNonLatin =  Remove-StringLatinCharacters -String $FirstName 
}
```

However this doesn't really work. It works in C# so what is the equivalent for this in PowerShell?

I am using this code in a way:

```
 $user = New-Object ActiveDirectoryUser   
 $user.DisplayName = $u.DisplayName
 $user.LastName = $u.LastName
 $user.FirstName = $u.FirstName

 $user | ft *  # should show all fields including FirstNameNonLatin
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a constructor to set the default value using another property. Ex:

```
function Remove-StringLatinCharacters ([string]$String) { $string.Substring(0,1) }

class ActiveDirectoryUser {
    [string]$DisplayName
    [string]$LastName
    [string]$FirstName
    [string]$FirstNameNonLatin

    ActiveDirectoryUser ([string]$DisplayName, [string]$LastName, [string]$FirstName) {
        $this.DisplayName = $DisplayName
        $this.LastName = $LastName
        $this.FirstName = $FirstName
        $this.FirstNameNonLatin =  (Remove-StringLatinCharacters -String $FirstName)
    }
}

[ActiveDirectoryUser]::new("Disp","Last","First")

DisplayName LastName FirstName FirstNameNonLatin
----------- -------- --------- -----------------
Disp        Last     First     F
```

Comment: Is there a way without constructor? I am using new-object and than adding what is nessecary one by one? I tried to use ( ) as i thought it would solve it but it doesn't do anything (empty string is returned).

Comment: There are no getters and setters in classes and you need something to trigger the expression which is what I used a constructor for. Without it, you would have to use a scriptproperty as @gvee shows below (added with `add-member`) or you could create a hidden property and a public method to retrieve it, but you would have to call `$myobj.FirstNameNonLatin()` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl

```
function Get-FormattedFullName {
    Param (
        [string]
        $FirstName
        ,
        [string]
        $LastName
    )

    Process {
        return "{0} {1}" -f $FirstName, $LastName
    }

}

$ActiveDirectoryUser = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$ActiveDirectoryUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty   -Name "FirstName" -Value "John"
$ActiveDirectoryUser | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty   -Name "LastName"  -Value "Smith"
$ActiveDirectoryUser | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "FullName"  -Value `
    { #Get
        return Get-FormattedFullName -FirstName $this.FirstName -LastName $this.LastName
    }
`

$ActiveDirectoryUser
```

Results:

```
FirstName LastName FullName    
--------- -------- --------    
John      Smith    John Smith
```

If we then update the `LastName` property of the object, the `FullName` reflects this change too:

```
$ActiveDirectoryUser.LastName = "CHANGED"

$ActiveDirectoryUser
```

Results:

```
FirstName LastName FullName    
--------- -------- --------    
John      CHANGED  John CHANGED
```

Comment: Don't think this is what I need. You are running the method at the assigning phase. Which is not what I need.

Comment: @MadBoy it might look like that, but it isn't.... I have updated the code with an example illustrating this.

Comment: He adds a property that is calculated every time you call it. That's the difference between a NoteProperty and a ScriptProperty (like @gvee has used)